# How big is the stack, and how much have I used up?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have an app using both java and C++. The latest version appears to have a corruption occurring in the C++ section which I suspect could be being caused by as stack overflow. So I would like to know:

- How much stack do I have?
- How much am I using?

Is there some call to interrogate these at run time?

Comment: Usually stack overflows should give a clear error on OS. They should only occur if you perform deep recursive calls, or if you place big objects on the stack (to my admittedly limited knowledge about the subject). Then it should not just flow into other memory space. Have you debugged the native part of your application?

Comment: A global variable is being overwritten. If I change the order of declaration of my global variables the crash does not occur and the program appears to work fine. I have a #define'd test for bad values of this global variable and it always fails at the same line in my code. but what happens between the previous successful test and the fail is simply an "if/else if/else if" chunk of code for which the answer is false in every case. There is no recursion in my code at all. I will have a look for big local arrays and make them static.

Comment: If you need to share them with your Java code, you could also put them to be on the Java heap.

Comment: Does [`pthread_attr_getstack`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_getstack) help you? I saw an Android using the `pthread_attr_setstack` method, so I presume it to be present. Just pushing my Google fu to its limit... May not be usuable on the main thread though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but I just discovered GCC's -fstack-usage flag. This may help.

Answer (score 0):

The default pthread stack size on Android is 1MB.  The default Dalvik stack size is much smaller (24 - 32KB), and the Dalvik stack is not shared with the native stack.  (In Art, the stacks are combined.)

A stack *overflow* would result in a crash unless you manage to write past the 4KB guard page.  It's unlikely that memory is arranged such that writing off the end of the thread stack would stomp on your globals, but it's not impossible.

Stack trashing is much easier to accomplish, but usually just results in other stuff on the stack getting hosed.  Again, overwriting a global is not likely.

It sounds like the failure is deterministic and you identified the code that's doing the trashing.  What does the code do?  What are the values (good and bad) held by the global?  Knowing what it's being trashed with -- a simple integer, a pointer, random garbage -- can be illuminating.

Comment: the global is an integer that should always be >=0 and <= 3. I sprinkled a #define'd check that it was in range all over the place, and suddenly it detects that its over 3000. The code between the successful test and the failure was if (a test) { stuff } else if (another test) ( stuff }, but the both the tests are false so it never even does the stuff.

Comment: "Over 3000" leaves a lot of room on a 32-bit int. :-)  Log the exact value -- maybe it's a pointer, maybe it's ASCII text, maybe it's a value you'll recognize.  See if it's the same on every run or changes every time.  Print the address of the global, and the address of a local on the stack in that function, and see if your globals and locals are anywhere near each other.  Add "dummy" globals before and after the one getting tweaked, set them to specific nonzero values, and see if they get changed to (indicating a single-integer update or a larger block-trashing).

Comment: by over 3000 I meant a specific value over 3000. Last time but one it was 3233 - but it changes from run to run. Last time it was 3221. And (after doing some stuff to reduce stack usage in general) the location of the corruption has changed. But all your advice is good, so thank you.